# Allow Transaction Signature only to wallets with eth

Tags: solidity, signature

I want to allow only addresses with eth above certain limit [Ex. 1ETH] to sign transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your sign function

```
require(address(msg.sender).balance >= 1 ether);
```